# Table view cell indexing when using insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

Ok, I'm stuck.  This is an extension of a previous post of mine.  Here is what I am trying to do.

I have an Edit button on a navigation bar that when pressed adds a cell at the beginning of my one section table view.  The purpose of this cell if to allow the use to add new data to the table; thus it's editing style is Insert.  The remaining cells in the table are configured with an editing style of Delete.

Here is my setediting method:

```
- (IBAction) setEditing:(BOOL)isEditing animated:(BOOL)isAnimated
{
    [super setEditing:isEditing animated:isAnimated];
    // We have to pass this to tableView to put it into editing mode.
    [self.tableView setEditing:isEditing animated:isAnimated];

  // When editing is begun, we are adding and "add..." cell at row 0.
  // When editing is complete, we need to remove the "add..." cell at row 0.
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  NSArray* path = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

  // fill paths of insertion rows here
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  if( isEditing )
   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:path withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
  else
   [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:path withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];

  // We nee to reload the table so that the existing table items will be properly 
  // indexed with the addition/removal of the the "add..." cell
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I am accounting for this extra cell in my code, except I now have two index paths = [0,0] - the new cell and the old original first cell in the table.  If I add a call to reload the table view cell in setEditing, the cells are re-indexed, but now my table view is no longer animated.

I want my cake and eat it too.  Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do and maintain animation?

--John

Comment: I've seen sample code where this is done except the new cell is added at the end of the table.  Not quite what I want - I want it at the beginning of the table.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Take Address Book as an example.  When you edit a contact a cell "add new address" is added with a "+" editing style at the end of the "Address" section.  I want to do something similar, except I want the new cell at the beginning of the section.  I can easily accomplish this by inserting the cell at indexPath [0,0].  But this gives me two cells at [0,0] (the new cell and the original cell at [0,0]).  I can fix this be reloading the table (re-indexes the cells), except when I do that the table is no longer animated when the edit button is pressed.

Comment: I'm curious what type of dataSource are you using? Is it an array or a fetchedresultcontroller, or something else?

Comment: The data source is just a data pair, like a title and subtitle.  I just used the Address Book as an example of the kind of thing I want to do with the cells.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information. Usually (not always) there is a data source that contains the objects that make up what goes into each cell and it's organized in a way that can be indexed like the cells. What does your tableView;cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: code loook like? If you have a configureCell method separate from these, can you show that code, too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want but you need to keep your data source consistent with the table. In other words, When the table is reloaded, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the other `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods responsible for building the table should return the same cells depending on editing state that you are adding/removing in `setEditing:antimated:`.

So, when you insert/delete a cell in `setEditing:animated:` you need to also make sure your data source reflects the same change. This can be tricky if you are adding a special cell to the beginning of a section but the rest of the data is from an array. One way to do this is while reloading the table, if editing, make row 0 the add cell and use row-1 for your array index for subsequent cells. If you do that you'd also need to add one to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to account for the extra cell.

Another way would be to have a section for the add cell and it would have 0 rows when not editing, 1 row otherwise and you return the appropriate cell. This will also require you to configure your table and cell(s) appropriate depending on how you want things to look.

Comment: I'm using the "-1" trick.  I edited my original post to show the setEditing code wih the reloadData.  If I don't reload the data, then I have two cells @ [0,0]; however reloading the data "kills" my animation when editing begins/ends.

Comment: You don't need to reload the whole table. You only need to insert/delete the affected section/rows. The integrity of the table is automatically preserved provided your data source also reflects the changes. You also don't need the 'beginUpdates/endUpdates' though it's not hurting anything. You only do that when making multiple changes that you want to animate at once. You are only making a single change.